# query to have all itms from one table but order by another table that doesn't have all items

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have one table `products` with **id** of product and **name**.

Second table is `products_last_usage` where I keep **product_id**, **user_id** and **last_used_at**.

Whenever a user clicks on a product, I have the field **last_used_at** updated.

Now, I need a query to list **all** products, and order them first by last_used_at, and then by name of product. It has to be **PER USER**. i.e. every user will have his own order of the table.

But I need all products, even if there are no records of them in the second table.

How to do that?

You can help me with a rails query or mysql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `left join`:

```
select p.*
from products p left join
     products_last_usage plu
     on plu.product_id = p.id and plu.user_id = $user_id
order by (last_used_at is not null) desc, last_used_at desc;
```

Ordering by `last_used_at desc` should also work.  However, I think it is clearer to explicitly handle `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start from something like this.  Pls next time post sample data, expected results etc.

```
SELECT A.PRODUCT_ID
  , A.PRODUCT_NAME
  , B.USER_ID
  , B.LAST_USED_AT
FROM PRODUCTS A
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS_LAST_USAGE B ON A.PRODUCT_ID = B.PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY B.USER_ID, B.LAST_USED_AT DESC, A.PRODUCT_NAME;
```